# Kendo UI/Angular: how to assign/obtain handler in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following color picker gadget in Kendo UI/Angular. Note that `k-on-change` works fine:

```
<input kendo-color-picker="theColor" k-on-change="c=theColor.value()" />
```

Now, what I need is to have several color picker gadgets in a list, like so (note that this doesn't work):

```
 <ul>
   <li style="list-style-type:none" ng-repeat="color in colors">
      <input kendo-color-picker="theColor" k-on-change="color.c=theColor.value()" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

The problem in the code above is that I cannot assign the same `theColor` handler to each of the occurrences. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KendoUI notes in their documentation that ng-repeat won't work properly after initialization. They recommend data-source instead and I've set up a working example [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/iTvvl6/preview)

You can use DataSource or ObservableArray. For example:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($compile, $scope) {

  $scope.tree = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([{
    text: "Foo",
    items: [{
      text: "Foo 1"
    }, {
      text: "Foo 2"
    }]
  }, {
    text: "Bar",
    items: [{
      text: "Bar 1"
    }, {
      text: "Bar 2"
    }]
  }, ]);
});
```

**html**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>AngularJS + kendo</h1>

  <div kendo-grid k-data-source="tree" k-columns='[
                      { "template":"<input kendo-color-picker=\"theColor\" k-on-change=\"color.c=theColor.value()\" />"}
                  ]'>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. what documentation says that ng-repeat won't work properly after initialization?

Comment: You can see it here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/notes-on-ng-repeat

Comment: isn't the scenario different? in your link the widget contains the ng-repeat, whereas in my scenario there are many widgets within each ng-repeat